# nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [my-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring

I'm relatively new to Java and trying to learn spring framework. I have the following code

```
public class EmployeeTest {
    public static void main(String ...args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("my-config.xml");
        Employee employee = (Employee) ctx.getBean("emp");
        System.out.println(employee.getId());
        System.out.println(employee.getName());

    }
}
```

where `my-config.xml` is located where the `EmployeeTest` class itself is. However, when I'm running this code, I get the following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [my-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [my-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

I tried to place my-config.xml under `src/main/java` as some of the articles suggest, still no luck

I'm using IntelliJ Idea as an editor.
Any hints are greatly appreciated

Comment: If you are trying to access the config file via the classpath, it needs to be in `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 3):

If you use Maven to build your application, you should put the `my-config.xml` file to `src/main/resources` directory

Comment: yes, thank you!!! It worked

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found a solution. So I created a `resources` directory under `src/main` and placed my `my-config.xml` there. After it started working

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring's `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` class.  As the name of the class implies (and the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html) says) this loads its config files from the application classpath.

But the contents of the `src/main/java` tree are not on the classpath.  Put the file into `src/main/resources` ... which will (typically) be added directly to the classpath directly, or added to the JAR or WAR file that Maven / Gradle / your IDE generates.

See also:

- [Maven: Introduction to the standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

---

> I tried to place `my-config.xml` under `src/main/java` as some of the articles suggest, still no luck.

Yea ... no.  Unless you do other (probably inadvisable) things, files in the `src/main/java` are not on the classpath, and won't be found by `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.

<sup>If those articles *really* suggested this as a solution for *this* context, then they are just plain wrong.  That approach *could* sort of work if you were using `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` ... but using a relative pathname is fragile (it depends on what the app's *working directory* is), and a pathname that refers to your source tree typically won't work when you deploy your application in production.</sup>